# Coupled differential equations into system of first-order equations implicitly

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I am looking to solve the following equations numerically:

$a x=\frac{d}{dt}\left(f(x,y,t)\frac{dy}{dt}\right),\quad b y=\frac{d}{dt}\left(g(x,y,t)\frac{dx}{dt}\right)$

For arbitrary functions $f$ and $g$ and constants $a$ and $b$.
I am struggling to find a way to transform this into a system of first order differential equations that I can pass into a solver. It looks like I will need to define these implicitly, but I'm not sure how to do that.

My best attempt so far is the following:

\begin{align}z_1&=f(x,y,t)\frac{dy}{dt}\\
z_2&=g(x,y,t)\frac{dx}{dt}\\
z_3&=ax\\
z_4&=by\\
\end{align}

\begin{equation}\begin{pmatrix}z_1\\z_2\\z_3\\z_4\end{pmatrix}'=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&\frac{a}{g(t,x,y)}&0&0\\\frac{b}{f(t,x,y)}&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}z_1\\z_2\\z_3\\z_4\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

However, this seems fairly inelegant and assumes that you are always able to divide by $f$ and $g$. I'm trying to keep this as general as possible, so don't want to make that assumption. Is there a better way to turn this into a system of first order differential equations implicitly? Thanks!

Comment: You always have to exclude $f=0$ and $g=0$ from the domain of the ODE system, as on those surfaces the order of the system collapses, the system becomes singular there. Now you could ask under what circumstances a solution can be prolonged into these singular sets and continued (uniquely?) on the other side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rather define $u = x'$ and $v = y'$. Then, your system becomes
\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix}
x'\\y'\\fv'\\gu'
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
u\\v\\
ax -f_xuv -f_yv^2\\
by -g_xu^2 - g_yuv
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

As long as $f\neq 0\neq g$, this is a nonlinear system of first order ODEs. If, at a certain point, $f=0$, or $g=0$, or both, then this system is a differential-algebraic equation (DAE, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential-algebraic_system_of_equations) and [here](https://www3.math.tu-berlin.de/Vorlesungen/SS14/NumericsDAE/dae_seminar24.04.pdf)). Numerical methods for DAEs are well studied and available. For instance, see [Matlab built-in function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/solve-differential-algebraic-equations-daes.html).